# How to Convert 24 to 8 bit depth PNG Image using OpenCV C++

Tags: c++, image, opencv

**I want to convert 24bit png images to 8bit png images**

I tried several methods, but they failed.

I'd like to convert the color 24-bit png_images to **color 8-bit png_images**

However, if I try to convert to an 8-bit image, **it becomes gray scale.**

I want to use an **imwrite().** But anything doesn't matter.

Below is my full code.

```
#include <oppencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp> //for resize
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

void overlayImage(const Mat &background, const Mat &foreground, Mat &output, 
Point2i location);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    Mat image_background;
    Mat black_background;
    Mat image_target, image_segmentation;

    image_target = imread("panda.png", IMREAD_UNCHANGED);   //  Transparent PNG


    image_segmentation = imread("panda_segmentation_stroke.png", IMREAD_UNCHANGED);

    string filename, filename2;

    vector<String> fn;

    glob("C:\\Users\\IMRC\\source\\repos\\OpenCVProject\\OpenCVProject\\background\\*.jpg", fn, false);

    size_t count = fn.size();
    cout << "Image Size " << count << "\n";

    float MIN_SIZE = 0.3;
    float MAX_SIZE = 0.8;

    float WIDTH = 300;
    float HEIGHT = 400;
    float SIZE_WIDTH, SIZE_HEIGHT, Point_x, Point_y;  // random size and point 


    string JPEGImagesPath = "C:\\Users\\IMRC\\DESKTOP\\TEST\\JPEGImages\\2019-";
    string SEG_ImagesPath = "C:\\Users\\IMRC\\DESKTOP\\TEST\\SegmentationClass\\2019-";

    srand(static_cast <unsigned> (time(0)));

    black_background = imread(fn[0], IMREAD_COLOR);
    resize(black_background, black_background, Size(500, 500));

    for (size_t i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        cout << fn[i] << "\n";

        image_background = imread(fn[i], IMREAD_COLOR);                           
        black_background.setTo(Scalar(0, 0, 0));

        resize(image_background, image_background, Size(500,500));                    // background image resize

        Mat image_resize_target;
        Mat image_resize_segmentation;


        SIZE_WIDTH = MIN_SIZE + static_cast <float> (rand()) /( static_cast <float> (RAND_MAX / (MAX_SIZE - MIN_SIZE)));
        SIZE_HEIGHT = MIN_SIZE + static_cast <float> (rand()) / (static_cast <float> (RAND_MAX / (MAX_SIZE - MIN_SIZE)));

        Point_x = static_cast <float> (rand()) / (static_cast <float> (RAND_MAX / WIDTH));
        Point_y = static_cast <float> (rand()) / (static_cast <float> (RAND_MAX / HEIGHT));

        resize(image_target, image_resize_target, Size(), SIZE_WIDTH, SIZE_HEIGHT);                
        resize(image_segmentation, image_resize_segmentation, Size(), SIZE_WIDTH, SIZE_HEIGHT);

        overlayImage(image_background, image_resize_target, image_background, cv::Point(Point_x, Point_y));
        overlayImage(black_background, image_resize_segmentation, black_background, cv::Point(Point_x, Point_y));


        stringstream JPEGImages, SEG_Images, SEG_RawImage;
        JPEGImages   << JPEGImagesPath    << i + 1 << ".jpg";
        SEG_Images   << SEG_ImagesPath    << i + 1 << ".png";

        filename = JPEGImages.str();
        imwrite(filename, image_background);  // save JPEGImages

        filename2 = SEG_Images.str();   
        imwrite(filename2, black_background); // save SegmentationClass

    }

    return 0;
}

void overlayImage(const Mat &background, const Mat &foreground, Mat &output, Point2i location)
{
    background.copyTo(output);

    // start at the row indicated by location, or at row 0 if location.y is negative.
    for (int y = std::max(location.y, 0); y < background.rows; ++y)
    {
    int fY = y - location.y;   // because of the translation

    if (fY >= foreground.rows) // we are done of we have processed all rows of the foreground image.
        break;

    // start at the column indicated by location, 

    // or at column 0 if location.x is negative.
    for (int x = std::max(location.x, 0); x < background.cols; ++x)
    {
        int fX = x - location.x;    // because of the translation.

        if (fX >= foreground.cols)  // we are done with this row if the column is outside of the foreground image.
            break;

        // determine the opacity of the foregrond pixel, using its fourth (alpha) channel.
        double opacity = ((double)foreground.data[fY * foreground.step + fX * foreground.channels() + 3]) / 255.;
            // and now combine the background and foreground pixel, using the opacity, 

            // but only if opacity > 0.
            for (int c = 0; opacity > 0 && c < output.channels(); ++c)
            {
                unsigned char foregroundPx = foreground.data[fY * foreground.step + fX * foreground.channels() + c];
                unsigned char backgroundPx = background.data[y * background.step + x * background.channels() + c];
                output.data[y*output.step + output.channels()*x + c] = backgroundPx * (1. - opacity) + foregroundPx * opacity;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The purpose of this code is to synthesize.

After preparing background images and another png_images, And exporting the composed image.

**I want to print this image as an 8 bit colored png image.**

How do I modify the source code?

Add Picture
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oj000.png)

Comment: `24-bit`, refers to the `24-bit pixel size`, `8 bits per color channel`.

Comment: You mean a single channel image with a palette (such as PNG format allows)? Can't write those with OpenCV, Since you're in C++, maybe using libpng directly is the way to go.

Comment: The process you want is called dithering, and a quick search of the OpenCV documentation doesn't turn up anything - apparently this common function isn't offered. You'll need to search elsewhere, there are even a couple of answers here on StackOverflow.

Comment: Have a look here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/54906864/2836621

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Mat::convertTo](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=convertto#mat-convertto) function to change the type of your `cv::Mat`. I am assuming that the image that you want to convert to an 8-bit one is of type `CV_32SC3` (or `CV_32SC4` if you have an alpha channel). Even if my guess is not correct, you can learn the right image type using [cv::Mat::type()](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-type). You can then convert your image to a `CV_8UC3` using the first function above. Note that the conversion function accepts a scaling factor, `alpha`. This should be set properly, which would otherwise cause integer overflow. You can figure out the right scaling factor according to what `cv::Mat::type()` gives you. Hope this helps!

Edit : You can check what the result of `type()` means [here](http://ninghang.blogspot.com/2012/11/list-of-mat-type-in-opencv.html).

Synopsis of [cv::imwrite](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgcodecs/doc/reading_and_writing_images.html#imwrite) says that the only parameter you can tweak is the image quality when writing a `PNG` file. Changing the number of channels of your OpenCV image is the only second way to set the image properties which we already discussed above. As a result, obtaining an 8-bit *color* PNG is possible only through using a palette. Check `libpng`'s documentation where it says [If you are writing an indexed colors image, you should provide a palette (colormap)](https://www.nongnu.org/pngpp/doc/0.2.9/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I got the result of 16 using `cout << black_background.type()` And I used `black_background.convertTo(Output, CV_8UC3, 1);` to extract images. But the results were the same. It's my first time using Opencv Project. so, it's too difficult. Give me some more help.

Comment: I added a link in the answer. Apparently your image has three channels and is already at 8-bit resolution. Can you be more clear on what you mean by 8-bit PNG?

Comment: oh, i'm so sorry. I added a picture. 
In the language of my country, it was written only as an image bit. When I switched the language to English for capture, it was bit depth. What should I do about this?