# Convert RGB Color Image to Indexed Color Image Type in OpenCV C++

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to convert rgb image to indexed color type.

Here is my Code C++. This is convert to gray scale.

what should I do?

```
Mat black_background = imread("image_path", IMREAD_COLOR); 

Mat output;
cvtColor(black_background, output, cv::COLOR_RGB2GRAY);

imwrite("save_path", output);
```

Comment: Maybe you can look this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49710006/fast-color-quantization-in-opencv) and this [blog](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/07/07/color-quantization-opencv-using-k-means-clustering/)

Comment: and https://stackoverflow.com/a/35482205/5008845

Comment: One problem is that you won't be able to use `imwrite` to save such image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not believe **OpenCV**'s `imwrite()` supports writing a palettised PNG. One option may be to write as any other format you like and convert to a palettised PNG with **ImageMagick** afterwards.

**ImageMagick** is included in most Linux distros and is available for macOS and Windows.

So, in Terminal, or Command Prompt on Windows:

```
magick input.png PNG8:result.png
```

Prior to v7 of **ImageMagick** that would be:

```
convert input.png PNG8:result.png
```

The `PNG8:` prefix forces a palettised result.

---

If you don't want to have to go around converting your files explicitly afterwards, you could write them using **OpenCV**'s `imwrite()` as PNG files in the filesystem and then use C++'s `system()` to get **ImageMagick** to convert them:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

...

imwrite('result.png', image);

// Delegate conversion to palette image to ImageMagick
system("magick result.png PNG8:result.png');
```

---

For the more anxious/astute readers:

- yes, unlike with other Unix utilities, it is ok to use the same file for input as output with **ImageMagick** and there is no fear of corruption because the file is read in its entirety before being processed and then written out,
- yes, **ImageMagick** will implicitly take care of the quantisation necessary to reduce the colours in the image to a palette version,
- yes, you can force other types of `PNG` file with other prefixes, e.g. `RGB24:result.png` will result in RGB888 output, `RGB32:result.png` will result in RGBA8888 output, `RGB48:result.png` will result in 16-bit red, 16-bit green and 16-bit blue and so on.

Comment: Remark: For those who want to port to android/ios, may use png++ or libpng :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61355551/how-to-create-and-write-an-indexed-png-image-in-c-or-c

Comment: It's unbelievable that OpenCV doesn't have support for that. applyColorMap creates 3 channel image...

Answer (score 1):

I write down my own encoder/decoder for indexed color image, by *manually* encode/decode the BMP and PNG format. It works well for me (in production environment).

The idea of the code: Manually look at the blocks inside BMP/PNG (e.g. the PLTE block in png). The sample code is below, and you can also write/modify to your own.

The usage of the code:

```
// sample usage
int main() {
  Mat image_index = ...;
  Mat palette = ...;
  vector<uchar> encoded_bytes = imencode_palette_bmp(image_index, palette);
}
```

Full code (gist): https://gist.github.com/fzyzcjy/8b1736a294aab81eb86243bfb6fdc260